# Div doesn't take up height of iframe

Tags: html, css

Please refer to this http://jsfiddle.net/7wt8L/1/

I tried embedding an iframe in a div for which I did not specify any height. I expected the iframe to fill up the div but there's some space at the bottom of the div.

I do know how to make the div take the height of the iframe but I'm curious to why there's the space at the bottom of the yellow div when I don't specify the height of the yellow div. I'm also slightly confused that giving the iframe a property of `display:block` allows the div to take the height of the iframe too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iframes are `display: inline` by default. Inline elements can be affected by many things, including `line-height`, `vertical-align` etc. Try setting your `line-height` to 0 on the parent of the iframe, you'll see the margin will disappear. http://jsfiddle.net/7wt8L/2/

If you don't want those text-oriented properties effecting your elements, use `display: block;` instead.

Answer (score 0):

iframes `display inline` by default.

So if you are going with `margin: auto;` ( as you have not set margin so by default its `margin : auto`) you will need to add `display: block`; as well.

Also for auto margins to work an explicit width must be set on the `iframe` (which you did).